Are flags on this meta handled at all?
I know the queues for meta-flags are separate from the ones for the main site. Is any mod here handling the former?
There was a (IMHO) rambunctious exchange between two [other] users here under one of my [meta] answers, and despite me flagging the exchange (admittedly--after a while--mainly in the hope I don't keep getting that red notification for stuff I don't care about), nothing happened, but the flags were not cleared either.

Has this been handled? I know as a mod on other SE sites that we mods will never notice about mod flags on meta unless we visit meta, because there's no indicator about it from the main site.
